# Can I add music to iPhone from a computer without my full library?

Tags: iphone, itunes, music

I just got a new MacBook, and I won't be able to restore the files from my previous MacBook (which isn't with me) for a couple of weeks. That older computer has my music library and syncs with my iPhone. In the meantime I'd like to add a couple of albums from my new laptop if possible. Can I add those albums from iTunes without deleting all the music already on my iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

No, the phone can only be synced with one computer over the cable. If you purchase an apple music subscription, your music is cloud-hosted and you have more flexibility.